# how to manage colima <> docker effectively

Tags: docker, apple-silicon, colima

Im trying to learn more about docker with colima especially on apple-silicon,

so far... I understand the basics of it and how both actually work together.
But I do have some question about how to manage it so far as :

**- stopping colima directly without loosing data/containers**

> (`colima stop [c-id]` before or after `docker stop [c-id]`, is it needed ?)*

**- restart colima easily without having to setup everything (colima actually drains a lot of RAM)**

> (right now, when ever I stop colima and restart it, I can't see my past containers working running ( I think it is because it stops them too).*

> (Specially for different ARCH, I want to know if there's a way to stop colima and then restart it without having to care about inner dockers container states.)*

**- how to switch default Deamon on colima**

> (how to switch so far the default deamon whenever we use `colima start`.)

**- manage deamons names**

> (I haven't seen any way to rename existing deamons without recreating them on top.)

**- how to run colima on boot on a specific deamon**

**- change colima context without affecting docker**

**- having stats of colima deamon running (cpu & ram usage...=/= allocated)**

Thank you for your help, if any question isn't clear or doesn't make sens, feel free to quote it and correct it.

Answer (score 1):

> - stopping colima directly without loosing data/containers

When you execute docker stop [c-id], only the container whose ID you specify will stop. colima stop command is used to stop the VM colima is using for Docker. If you want your containers to start when the daemon starts, you need to use a [docker restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)

> - restart colima easily without having to setup everything (colima actually drains a lot of RAM)

You can't do that, and as I mentioned above, restarting the containers is something you need to apply. You also do not lose any data with colima.

> - how to switch default Deamon on colima

You can either change the configuration by running `colima start --edit` or pass your arguments to the terminal. Colima defaults to docker, but you can switch at any time by running `colima stop; colima start --runtime docker"` to use docker and `colima stop; colima start --runtime containerd"`

> - manage deamons names

I don't understand this question.

> - how to run colima on boot on a specific deamon

I saw the feature request a while ago, but I don't think this feature was released.

> change colima context without affecting docker

What do you mean by change colima context? Are you referring to the runtime? If yes, then you can't do that without impacting the running containers. Keep in mind that colima runs the docker engine for you, and you can't use both docker and containerd

> - having stats of colima deamon running (cpu & ram usage...=/= allocated)

Run colima status to see all resources the colima VM is using.

The colima team did a good job [documenting](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) the most important part of the tool.